# Selenium headless not working with custom profile selection

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code I'm using - I've attempted to make it as concise as possible.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import bs4

options=Options()
#options.add_argument('--headless') # Works while not headless?
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=profiles\\") #Keeps login data
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
html=driver.page_source
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

The main problem stems from the `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory` parameter. In my test example a custom chrome profile (usually found at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`) is in the current directory to keep it separate from any currently running chrome sessions.

If the `--headless` parameter is enabled while using the above parameters the driver hangs (the CMD stays and does not produce output on the Python command line). However, when not enabled the window pops open and performs as expected.

However, `--headless` does work while using any profile within the above default directory.

This is the console output;

```
[0120/222514.611:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(967)] Lost UI shared context.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59961/devtools/browser/ee317ed6-93c7-47c2-b26d-63647980ba0d
[0120/222514.619:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(289)] Error writing DevTools active port to file
[0120/222514.624:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(19)] Unable to move the cache: 0
[0120/222514.625:ERROR:cache_util.cc(140)] Unable to move cache folder profiles\Default\GPUCache to profiles\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[0120/222514.625:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0120/222514.625:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(622)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

So, it looks like somewhere Chromium is assuming I'm using the `Default` profile when in fact I specify I am not.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to your code to run with the following option added.

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=45447')
```

Without it the code was hanging for around a minute before the following error was thrown:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

**Comment excerpt which pointed me to a solution:**

> When you send --remote-debugging-port=0 to Chrome, devtools chooses
>   its own port and writes it to chrome::DIR_USER_DATA as a file
>   named "DevToolsActivePort".

Basically once the port is set to something other than the default of 0 the *DevToolsActivePort* file does not need to be checked. 
The full comment and bug are here: [chromedriver bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2161#c57)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've added the option and the same error occurs - but I think you might be onto something. Can you edit to show the exact snippet you were using so I can try and exactly recreate?

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused the only line I have added to your script is the one I mentioned in my answer and I uncommented the headless arg also. This seems to be more of an environmental issue in that case. Can you provide some more details on the way you have your env configured?

Comment: I've updated my chromedriver.exe, and although the same error appears the webdriver seems to function as expected. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: This removed the WebDriverException, tried and confirming that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by closing the command prompt and reopening it in administrator mode (right-click on the cmd.exe and click Run as administrator).

Nothing else worked.